# How to configurate Spring security 4 and JSF

Tags: spring, spring-security, jsf-2

I'm trying to set up Spring security 4.1 and JSF 2 (with primefaces 6.0 but this does not seem related).
My problem is that when I test my login.xhtml page and I introduce the wrong username and password, login.xhtml is reloaded, and this is correct, but when I enter the correct username and password it is the same.

I can see both parameters in the post method, this data is sent correctly, but for spring security are incorrect.

this is my configuration spring-security-config:

```
<http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/xhtml/frob/index.xhtml" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/xhtml/frob/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login login-page = "/login.xhtml" username-parameter="j_username" 
                password-parameter="j_password" 
                login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=1"/>
    <csrf disabled="true"/>  
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            <user name="user2" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER2" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

And this is login.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="login" action="/login.xhtml" method="POST">

   <h:outputLabel for="username" value="loginUser" />
   <h:inputText value="user" tabindex="1" id="username"/>
   <h:outputLabel value="Password" for="password" />
   <h:password value="pass" size="14" tabindex="2" id="password"/>
   <h:commandButton outcome="#{controlBean.next}" tabindex="3" value="Send"/>

</h:form>
```

I need some help, I'm using Spring security 4.1.

Comment: Did you try with a `h:inputText` and a `h:password` and a `h:commandButton`? I doubt it works there too. If not it is not PrimeFaces related and you have narrowed down the problem

Comment: Thanks but this not work. Regrds

Comment: So it is a plain spring/jsf issue.

Comment: maybe this can be useful: http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-security-jsf-2-primefaces-5-integration-annotation-example